# Efficiency model for centrifugal pumps, using relations from Europump's Ecopump project

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps, modeling, process-engineering, education

**Context:**

I'm trying to create a mathematical model for centrifugal pumps. This model should describes how the operational variables of centrifugal pumps $(Q, \Delta P, ...)$ related to it's design parameters $(Stages, Dimensions, ...)$ and it's use-case $(\rho, \mu, ....)$ .The intention behind this job is to develop an educational simulation environment. Anyway, after spending reasonable time reading+hacking various references I didn't find an *idiomatic, integrated, already provided model* to use. And I decided to assemble it using different parts from different sources.

Currently I think that:

- One important part of the model is to write $f(\eta,Q,...)=0$ or finding relation between **Efficiency**, **Flow** + **design parameters** on *allowable*, *preferred* or at list *rated* flow range.

**Proposal:**

To overcome the above bulleted item of my modeling problem, I picked mandatory conditions of an acceptable **Ecopump** project's centrifugal pump. Reference: [Assessing the Energy
Efficiency of Pumps and Pump Units](http://europump.net/news/22/44/HANDBOOK-ASSESSING-THE-ENERGY-EFFICIENCY-OF-PUMPS-AND-PUMP-UNITS) By: *Bernd Stoffel*

> **Ecopump** is the name of the successful flagship project that [Europump](http://www.europump.org/)
>   launched in 2004 to bring the pump industry’s commitment to energy
>   savings to the fore.

Following equations from the referred handbook, describes minimum $Efficiency$ required at these three different flow rates: 1-$BEP$, 2-part-load$(PL)$ and 3-over-load$(OL)$ , in terms of design parameters:

$\eta_{BEP,min\, requ} = -11.48*(\log(n_s))^2-0.85*(\log(Q_{BEP}))^2-
0.38*\log(n_s)*\log(Q_{BEP})+88.59*\log(n_s)+13.46*\log(Q_{BEP})\qquad (7.4)$

$\eta_{PL,min\, requ} = 0.947*\eta_{BEP,min\, requ}\qquad (7.5)$

$\eta_{OL,min\, requ} = 0.985*\eta_{BEP,min\, requ}\qquad (7.6)$

$#Where:$

$Q_{PL} = 0.75*Q_{BEP}$

$Q_{OL} = 1.1*Q_{BEP}$

Although the above conditions are three inequality rule that define a floor for a real pump $\eta$ value, I make an important suggestion here about a conceptual minimum Ecopump *which exactly overlays those minimum requirements* so $\eta_{real}==\eta_{min}$ ,and using those three points for $\eta$ it is possible to interpolate a second order polynomial and find $\eta(Q)$ for that conceptual minimum Ecopump with specific design parameters.

I expect that this model along with its numerical results could help instructors to cover following topics in a classic pump course:

1. How efficiency of a pump is related to other parameters.
2. How much a pump efficiency should be, to fulfill mandatory items of standards.
3. How does $\eta$ change related to $Q$
4. How to deal with modern standards about pump efficiency

**Questions:**

- **Part One:**
  Am I on the right way? Or is(are) there any better way(s) to achieve the mentioned four goals.

Also:
The original $(7.4)$ equation have an additional $-C$ constant with the following description:

> The constant C(in [%]) depends on **MEI** and additionally on the type and nominal speed of the size.

- **Part Two:**
  From the handbook it is not clear for me how to calculate this constant, but for my approximate educational model I simply put it aside, Is this approximation acceptable? How much it affects my model? How to substitute more accurate value for $C$?

Any idiomatic points to create a better model are appreciated.